# Horizontal list group Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want something similar to the styles of http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-basic but I want the sections to be horizontal.  This has to happen on mobile devices. Can we use list-group and list-inline together?

Answer (score 0):

@Amy : list-group will display the vertical line and list-inline will display the horizontal line as of your code.
So, we can not use them together. And if we use, it only shows result of list-inline.